# Nginx redirected too much

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, https, odoo

I am out of ideas of what is my `Nginx` configuration issue.

I'm using these docker images: 
`nginx`, `jwilder/docker-gen`, `jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion`, `odoo`, `postgres`

When I test the configuration from LAN the web app worked and the https reverse proxy worked.

But when I test in on internet I got redirected too much error. I watch the log and I can see the repeating redirection.

Log from LAN

```
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 192.168.130.127 - - [22/Nov/2019:05:21:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 303 215 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 192.168.130.127 - - [22/Nov/2019:05:21:29 +0000] "GET /web HTTP/2.0" 303 227 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 192.168.130.127 - - [22/Nov/2019:05:21:29 +0000] "GET /web/login HTTP/2.0" 200 4383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 192.168.130.127 - - [22/Nov/2019:05:21:29 +0000] "GET /web/content/269-ceb8fb1/web.assets_common.0.css HTTP/2.0" 499 0 "https://fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id/web/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 192.168.130.127 - - [22/Nov/2019:05:21:29 +0000] "GET /web/content/276-771d39e/web.assets_frontend.0.css HTTP/2.0" 499 0 "https://fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id/web/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 192.168.130.127 - - [22/Nov/2019:05:21:29 +0000] "GET /web/webclient/qweb?mods= HTTP/2.0" 304 0 "https://fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id/web/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 192.168.130.127 - - [22/Nov/2019:05:21:29 +0000] "POST /web/webclient/bootstrap_translations HTTP/2.0" 200 87 "https://fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id/web/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
```

Log from the Internet

```
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:42 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

Why `Nginx` reply differently 301 on internet vs 303 on LAN?

Here is my `Nginx` reverse proxy configuration for the web

```
# fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id
upstream fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id {
                                ## Can be connected with "nginx-proxy" network
                        # fhid_web_1
                        server 172.20.0.8:8069;
}
server {
        server_name fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
        server_name fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id.dhparam.pem;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/fhij.abcd.co.id.chain.pem;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id;
                proxy_connect_timeout      9990;
                proxy_send_timeout         9990;
                proxy_read_timeout         9990;
                proxy_send_lowat           12000;
        }
}
```

I have tried changing the upstream name to `fhij` and `proxy_pass http://fhij` with resulted the same error

I have also configure odoo `proxy_mode = True`

Comment: `proxy_pass http://fhij.fullertonhealth.co.id/ ; `in my mind the / is missing

Comment: Restart your browser between tests: they tend to remember 301 (permanent) redirects and never actually send a request again.

Comment: tested adding `/` does not change anything